# Express trigonometric expression assuming condition letter

Tags: trigonometry

Which is the syntax that allows to evaluate this expression in funtion of k

**If**
 $$Tan[310] = k$$
evaluate this expression in funtion of k
   $$\frac{Sin[320]-Cos[310]}{Tan[140]+Cot[220]}$$ 
**edit :
let $$Tan[310]=k$$
    an example for
  $$Cot[220] =Cot[180+40]=Cot[40]=tan[50]$$
  but
$$k=tan[310]=-tan[360-310]=-tan[50]$$
==>  $$Cot[220]=-k$$**

**edit 2
I solve by hand this expression 
$$\frac{Sin[320]-Cos[310]}{Tan[140]+Cot[220]}$$ 
with 
$$Tan[310]=k$$
came to
$$\frac{2k\sqrt{k^{2}+1}}{k^{4}-1}$$
came to
but it is very tedious
as an achievement that mathematica throw this result for this problem and for other longer?**

Comment: Could you clarify your question?  It makes no sense, especially the second part (which contains no $k$).

Comment: just that, beginning with the condition $tan (310) = k$ , as the expression remains in terms of k (as a function of k)

Comment: see edition plis

Comment: The solution is highly non-unique. One possibility is `(Sin[x + 10 Degree] - Cos[x])/(Tan[x - 170 Degree] + Cot[x - 90 Degree]) /. x -> ArcTan[k]`, which yields $$\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{k^2+1}}-\sin \left(\tan ^{-1}(k)+10 {}^{\circ}\right)}{k-\tan \left(\tan ^{-1}(k)+10 {}^{\circ}\right)}$$

Comment: This in a small example, the expression is different, it is assumed that the result is only in function of k, (I have tried several similar codes of the forum but none take the condition k = Tan [310]), the closest is written by AccidentalFourierTransform

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

Routine, that works for the given case.

```
eqs = {Tan[310 Degree] == k, 
      (Sin[320 Degree]-Cos[310 Degree])/(Tan[140 Degree] + Cot[220 Degree])==a}

eqs2 = eqs // TrigToExp

(*   {(I (E^(-40 I \[Degree]) + E^(40 I \[Degree])))/(
       E^(-40 I \[Degree]) - E^(40 I \[Degree])) == k, 
-((I (E^(-40 I \[Degree]) - E^(40 I \[Degree])))/(-((
 I (E^(-40 I \[Degree]) - E^(40 I \[Degree])))/(
 E^(-40 I \[Degree]) + E^(40 I \[Degree]))) - (
I (E^(-40 I \[Degree]) + E^(40 I \[Degree])))/(
E^(-40 I \[Degree]) - E^(40 I \[Degree])))) == a}   *)

eli = Eliminate[
        eqs2 /. (E^(-40 I \[Degree]) -> 1/c) /. (E^(40 I \[Degree]) ->c), c]

(*    (-4 - a^2) k^2 - a^2 k^4 + a^2 k^6 == -a^2   *)

sol=Solve[eli, a]

(*   {{a -> -((2 k)/Sqrt[1 - k^2 - k^4 + k^6])}, 
      {a -> (2 k)/Sqrt[1 - k^2 - k^4 + k^6]}}      *)
```

Some information got lost by Eliminate. Only the last is a valid solution.

```
eqs /. First@sol // Reduce

(*   False   *)

eqs /. Last@sol // Reduce

(*   k == -Cot[40 Degree]   *)
```

Comment: see my second edition